# Why Vertex-AI models wipe entrypoint or cmd of custom container settings with args or envs?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, google-cloud-vertex-ai, mlops, google-ai-platform

Usually when setting up MLOPS workflow with Docker container locally, it is good to set environment variables for docker build or docker run. Overriding Entrypoint can be useful in some cases.

So when importing custom model into custom container https://console.cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/models , the run mode should likely have args, but then why it is also erasing `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD` of the said docker container?
It is the same behavior using AIP sdk and [image: vertex UI].

Do you know why? It might be due to Kubernetes templating with specific sdk lifecycle.

How to make sure it is not erased ? (as an empty ENTRYPOINT will likely to return an exit code 0 - no error)

PS: I prefer not to show code as there are multiple ways to edit these kind of parameters so it is easier to understand (containerSpec / pure aip sdk / kfp...).